# React: unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting this error message, although my list elements do have a key :(

react.js:18745 Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `Thread`.

Here's my code:

```
render: function () {
    var messages = this.state.messagesCache.map(message => {
        return (message.own) ? (
            <li className="row own" key={message.id}>
                <p className="own message-body own-message-background small-5 medium-7 large-9 columns">
                    {message.body}
                </p>
                <p className="message-time small-2 large-1 columns">
                    {getTimePassed(message.timestamp)}
                </p>
            </li>
        ) : (
            <li className="row foreign" key={message.id}>
                <p className="foreign message-body foreign-message-background small-5 medium-7 large-9 columns">
                    {message.body}
                </p>
                <p className="message-time small-2 large-1 columns">
                    {getTimePassed(message.timestamp)}
                </p>
            </li>
        )
    })
    return this.state.currentThread ? (
        <div className="full-width">
            <ul className="inline-list uiScrollableArea">
                {messages}
            </ul>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="row" action="">
                <input className="small-12 columns" id={this.state.currentThread} autoComplete="off"
                       placeholder="input new message"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    ) : (
        <div>
            {"choose a thread to display"}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Many thanks for any help :)

Comment: What's up with `<div>{"choose a thread to display"}</div>` ? Why not `<div>choose a thread to display</div>` ?

Comment: @JuanMendes work in progress. I'm going to add there something making more sense later :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure, `message.id` is always unique. If not,

Try:

```
var messages = this.state.messagesCache.map((message,index) => {
        return (message.own) ? (
            <li className="row own" key={index}>
                <p className="own message-body own-message-background small-5 medium-7 large-9 columns">
                    {message.body}
                </p>
                <p className="message-time small-2 large-1 columns">
                    {getTimePassed(message.timestamp)}
                </p>
            </li>
        ) : (
            <li className="row foreign" key={index}>
                <p className="foreign message-body foreign-message-background small-5 medium-7 large-9 columns">
                    {message.body}
                </p>
                <p className="message-time small-2 large-1 columns">
                    {getTimePassed(message.timestamp)}
                </p>
            </li>
        )
    })
```

Comment: You were right! After few hours research I found out that the IDs weren't actually different sometimes. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Your paragraphs (p) are also recurring items. You can add keys to the paragraphs also. These keys kan be fixed (e.g. 'body' for the first paragraph and 'ts' or 'timestamp' for the second).